# Hyper v0.14 : http2 error: stream error sent by user: unexpected internal error encountered

Tags: hyper, reqwest

[`hyper::Client.request()`](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.14.26/hyper/client/struct.Client.html#method.request) occationally raises the following error in my http reverse proxy when forwarding an HTTP2 request.

> http2 error: stream error sent by user: unexpected internal error encountered

I am trying to find the cause of this error in [hyper v0.14 source code](https://github.com/hyperium/hyper/tree/0.14.x) but failed.  Can someone point me where this error is raised from hyper?  Wanna understand the cause.

Thanks in advance